# Populating PDF with Cocoa - Use NSTextField contents to populate a PDF text field?

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa, pdf, pdf-form

I have a simple macOS app programmed in cocoa with several NSTextFields that I would like to use as a means to gather some information such as name and telephone number from a customer. I would like to send that data to a blank PDF form, that I have created separately at a drive location, on execution of a button action.

The PDF form has known text field names, but how do I pass the data from the macOS app to the corresponding PDF text fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen an easy way to do this with just the built in cocoa classes.  PDFKit has `PDFDocument`, `PDFPage` and so on, but it's not clear you can modify the document via PDFKit.  There's a commercial SDK `PSPDFKit` that can do what you want, but I think the reason they exist is because it's not easy to do with Cocoa itself.

One way without buying a third party SDK is to describe your form templates in XML (or something) and then create the view using native AppKit controls and then save it as a PDF.  See the [Quartz](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) and [PDFKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863) in particular.

Note that you don't have to display the full template - the user can edit in a simplified window and then you can build the full view from your template description (XML say) offscreen view and then use `[NSView dataWithPDF(inside:)][3]` to get the NSDat